# Regular Expressions -  alphabet $(a, b, c)$

Tags: formal-languages

I'm not exactly sure how to go about this.

Thanks

Comment: Is this maybe a StackOverflow question? Please show what you need it for, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: No, this wouldn't be a StackOverflow question. I just need to show the expression which expresses the alphabet $(a, b, c)$ using the language I have mentioned above. I'm not sure how to do this, but i have done something like $(a|b|c|aaa|bbb|ccc)$ and so on, including every odd charactered combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

What language does $(aa)^*$ represent over the alphabet $\{a\}$?

Comment: So would it be $a^*|b^*|c^*$?

Comment: What you have mentioned represents the language of all words that have even length.

Comment: @akshai5050: No, $a*|b*|c*$ is not correct. You can verify it yourself, by trying out some sample strings. Yes to the second comment.

Comment: Yes, I now realise what I said wouldn't be correct, as even lettered words would also be accepted by the expression. So, would it then be $a(aa)^*|b(bb)^*|c(cc)^*$?

Comment: @akshai5050: What about words like $abc$? You miss those, don't you?

Comment: Yes, now given that you can represent all words that have even length, how can you extend that idea to all words of odd length?

Comment: @Aryabhata: $a(aa)^∗|b(bb)^∗|c(cc)^∗|abc|cba|acb|bca|bac|cab$  would this be ok?

Comment: or could it be changed to: $a(aa)^∗|b(bb)^∗|c(cc)^∗|(a(aa)^*b(bb)^*c(cc)^*)^*$?

Comment: @akshai5050: Trying solving the problem when the alphabet is $\{a,b\}$. Try and see if you can do words which mix $a$ and $b$.

Comment: From what I understand, that would not be possible, because of the $c$ before $(cc)^*$. I am not sure how to go about solving this though.

Comment: @akshai5050: Is there a regular expression for the language where the string is either $a$ or $b$?

Comment: Yes, this part: $a(aa)^∗|b(bb)^∗$

Comment: @Aryabhata $$a(aa)^∗|b(bb)^∗|c(cc)^∗|(a(aa)^∗b(bb)^∗c(cc)^*)^*|(a(aa)^*b(bb)^*)^*|(b(bb)^*c(cc)^*)^*|(a(aa)^*c(cc)^*)^*$$                                            I think this is right.

Comment: @akshai5050: No. For the two letter case, you miss words like $abababb$. It is not just $aaaaa$ or $bbbbb$. Ok, here is a question, how would you represent the set of _all_ possible strings using the alphabet $\{a,b\}$?

Comment: @Aryabhata $(a|b|c)((a|b|c)(a|b|c))^*$

Comment: @Aryabhata The answer to your question would be: $(a^*b^*)^*$

Comment: @akshai5050: Well done, seems like you got it. In the last one, why not just write (a|b)*?

Comment: @Aryabhata Yes, you're right. Thanks a lot for the help. Much appreciated.